# SQL Query conditional on results of another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a table of football data called 'Data' but I only wish to return data for a given 'DateKickOff'. The problem that I have is that the kick off date is stored in a different table called 'Match'. Both tables contain a column called MatchID so I am able to run this query:

```
SELECT MatchID FROM Match WHERE DateKickOff='10/08/2013'
```

to get a list of the MatchID's that I am interested in. I then wish to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Data
```

but return only results where the MatchID is present in the result of the first query. I would really appreciate if somebody could advise me on how to go about doing this. Thanks

Comment: What is the data type for your date column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [sub-query](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm) as well

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM Data
   Where MatchID IN (SELECT MatchID FROM Match WHERE DateKickOff='10/08/2013')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT d.* FROM Data d INNER JOIN Match m ON m.MatchID = d.MatchID 
WHERE DateKickOff = '10/08/2013'
```